# Immediately expand \thepage (custom TOC)

Tags: macros, expansion

I want to define a command to add a line to a TOC with the page number where the command is called. The first try was:

```
\def\mytoc{}
\def\addlinetomytoc#1{
    \g@addto@macro\mytoc{
        #1\dotfill\thepage\par
    }
}
```

In this way, then I call `\toc`, each line reports the page number of the TOC, and I understood why.

So I modified this way:

```
\def\mytoc{}
\def\addlinetomytoc#1{
    \edef\@tmp{\thepage}
    \g@addto@macro\mytoc{
        #1\dotfill\@tmp\par
    }
}
```

In this case, I get for all the lines the page number of the last time I call `\addlinetomytoc`, and I understood why too. But now I'm stuck and cannot find other solutions.

I cannot do something like `\edef\mytoc{...}` because `\dotfill` doesn't work in `\edef` (without `\dotfill` I get what I need).

I've been trying to do this a couple hours, but I cannot find any solution. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what this is useful for, because `\thepage` will typically point to a wrong page number, unless you issue `\addlinetomytoc` after `\clearpage`.

Anyway, you have to expand `\thepage` when adding the tokens:

```latex
\def\mytoc{}
\def\addlinetomytoc#1{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\mytoc{%
      \unexpanded{#1\dotfill}\thepage\noexpand\par
    }% end of \g@addto@macro
  }\x
}
```

This way `\x` becomes

```latex
\endgroup\g@addto@macro{#1\dotfill}<expansion of \thepage>\par}
```

and executing `\x` will do the right thing.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to understand why it does work.